# How to link tables with MYSQL JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

There are 4 tables. I want to link all tables with the current ID. If there is no value in the last table in my query, the data does not return. I want to access the data in all tables. How should I proceed for this?

**MY CODE: (Partially Working)**

```
SELECT 
    U.id AS id,
    U.amount AS amount,
    A.commission AS commission,
    I.power AS item_power
FROM affiliate AS A
     INNER JOIN users AS U
ON A.owner_id = U.id 
     INNER JOIN users_booster AS B
ON U.id = B.userid
     INNER JOIN auction_item AS I
ON B.item_id = I.id
    WHERE 
A.partner_id = '1947' AND 
I.type = 'reference_booster' AND
B.end_time >= NOW()
GROUP BY I.type
```

[image]

Comment: "access the data in all tables" is not a clear description of what you want. Neither is a bunch of arrows. Nobody could take what you wrote & know what your query is supposed to do or why you think it would do that. (They could guess at it.) Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. Please in code questions give a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `left join`.  And no `group by` is needed:

```
SELECT U.id AS id, U.amount AS amount, A.commission AS commission,
      I.power AS item_power
FROM affiliate A JOIN
     users U
     ON A.owner_id = U.id JOIN
     users_booster B
     ON U.id = B.userid LEFT JOIN
     auction_item I
     ON B.item_id = I.id AND I.type = 'reference_booster'
WHERE A.partner_id = 1947 AND 
      B.end_time >= NOW();
```

Notes:

- Use `LEFT JOIN` whenever you want to keep rows, even if there is no match.
- The condition on the *second* table in the `LEFT JOIN` needs to be in the `ON` clause.
- I imagine that `partner_id` is a number, so don't compare it to a string.  Use `1947` instead of `'1947'`.  Of course, if it is a string, keep the single quotes.
- `GROUP BY` rarely makes sense with no aggregation functions.

Comment: If there is no data belonging to the user, (1000) ID number data cannot be displayed.